# how to connect my html and js files?

Tags: javascript, html

my js is not work with my html file. how do that
if i open my html page, i`ll see just text inputs but result i cannot see

```js
function computeLoan() {
 var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
 var interest_rate = document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;
 var months = document.getElementById('months').value;
 var interest = (amount * (interest_rate* .01)) / months;
 var payment = ((amount / months) + interest).toFixed(2);
 payment = payment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,",");
 document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = "Monthly Payment =$"+payment; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="calc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Loan Amount: $<input id="amount" type="number" min="1" max="10000" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
 <p>Interest Rate: <input id="interest_rate" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="10" step=".1" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
 <p>Months: <input id="Months" type="number" min="1" max="72" value="1" step="1" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
 <h2 id="payment"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementById('months')` ... but `id="Months"` ... simple typo error ... see how `months` is not the same as `Months` ?

Comment: Do you have legos?

Comment: You need to check the error console in your browser as your first step in debugging these problems. This can be found in developer tools, which is F12 in most browsers. Developer Tools can also show you if your javascript file (and other external) resources have been successfully loaded. If you can't solve the problem yourself after checking the error console, make sure you report the errors if you ask  a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

**It seems like you made a typo** (you said `Months` instead of `months` in the HTML). If you fix that, it should work.

```js
function computeLoan() {
 var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
 var interest_rate = document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;
 var months = document.getElementById('months').value;
 var interest = (amount * (interest_rate* .01)) / months;
 var payment = ((amount / months) + interest).toFixed(2);
 payment = payment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,",");
 document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = "Monthly Payment =$"+payment; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="calc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Loan Amount: $<input id="amount" type="number" min="1" max="10000" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
 <p>Interest Rate: <input id="interest_rate" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="10" step=".1" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
 <p>Months: <input id="months" type="number" min="1" max="72" value="1" step="1" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
 <h2 id="payment"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @fiorentina.gf You're welcome! If my answer was helpful, would you mind marking it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in you code:

**First: typo**

You mistyped `document.getElementById('Months')` to `document.getElementById('months')`

**Second: function not called**

I'm not sure whether you called the function in your `calc.js` file, but from your example, you only declared the function and forgot to call it.

You can simply add `computedLoad()` to call it.

**Working code:**

```js
function computeLoan() {
  var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
  var interest_rate = document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;

  // PROBLEM HERE
  // var months = document.getElementById('months').value;

  // CORRECTED
  var months = document.getElementById('Months').value;

  var interest = (amount * (interest_rate* .01)) / months;
  var payment = ((amount / months) + interest).toFixed(2);
  
  payment = payment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,",");
  
  document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = "Monthly Payment =$"+payment; 
}


// ADD THIS
computeLoan();
```

```html
<p>Loan Amount: $<input id="amount" type="number" min="1" max="10000" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
<p>Interest Rate: <input id="interest_rate" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="10" step=".1" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
<p>Months: <input id="Months" type="number" min="1" max="72" value="1" step="1" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
<h2 id="payment"></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <p>Loan Amount: $<input id="amount" type="number" min="1" max="10000" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
    <p>Interest Rate: <input id="interest_rate" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="10" step=".1" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
    <p>Months: <input id="months" type="number" min="1" max="72" value="1" step="1" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
    <h2 id="payment"></h2>
</body>
<!-- it should be lower -->
<script src="calc.js"></script>

</html>
```

document.getElementById may be not find your id, write at bottom of your source

Answer (score 0):

You used `Months` instead of `months` (it should be `document.getElementById("Months")` instead of `document.getElementById("months")`)---remember that element `id`s are case sensitive. Also, I recommend using the `onkeyup` event along with `onchange` which only fires when the element loses focus (if typing). This way, the results will be computed while you type or while you change the value in the input box with the up and down arrows. To see the result when the page loads, call the function when the page loads.

```js
function computeLoan() {
 var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
 var interest_rate = document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;
 var months = document.getElementById('Months').value;
 var interest = (amount * (interest_rate* .01)) / months;
 var payment = ((amount / months) + interest).toFixed(2);
 payment = payment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,",");
 document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = "Monthly Payment =$"+payment; 
}
window.onload= function(){
 computeLoan();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="calc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Loan Amount: $<input id="amount" type="number" min="1" max="10000" onkeyup="computeLoan()" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
 <p>Interest Rate: <input id="interest_rate" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="10" step=".1" onkeyup="computeLoan()" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
 <p>Months: <input id="Months" type="number" min="1" max="72" value="1" step="1" onkeyup="computeLoan()" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>
 <h2 id="payment"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```